# Using bootstrap (theme) javascript in aurelia app

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, aurelia

I'm trying to use a bootstrap theme in an aurelia app and I experienced some issues with the bootstrap JavaScript components.

I included all of the sources needed for the bootstrap theme in aurelias `index.html`, so all of the JavaScript should be right in place.

### The issue(s):

I.e. there are components using the `href` attribute of an `a` tag to reference the corresponding dom-element for some toggling action, while aurelia is trying to navigate to the route of that `href` instead. (For a bootstrap tab navigation a workaround could be to use aurelias childrouter.)

Unfortunately I also didn't get a simple bootstrap modal to work in an aurelia app. It was a simple copy and paste from the bootstrap docs and should work fine  but nothing happens when I click the <kbd>Show modal</kbd> button.

How to use the JavaScript components of bootstrap in aurelia? Is there any way to get it to work?

Comment: I've written a blog about creating custom elements for wrapping css frameworks here: http://davismj.me/blog/semantic-custom-element/

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [PWKad's Aurelia Bootstrap Modal](https://github.com/PWKad/aurelia-bs-modal).

If you want to make any javascript components of Bootstrap to work in Aurelia, you must understand how they work, and you'll need to manually call the needed methods in the `attached` event.

A simple Bootstrap Modal, with no special capabilities, working in Aurelia can be seen in this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/hmI3wdjVjXSmf5SIhIQE?p=preview).

Comment: I just saw the Plnkr. Is there any way to capture the #modal events in Aurelia VM? like 

$('#modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {...}

Answer (score 1):

I'm simply addressing the very last sentence of the question.

I would take a look at the Aurelia docs, specifically the Contact Manager tutorial by Rob Eisenberg:

[Aurelia DocHub: Contact Manager](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/contact-manager-tutorial/1)

This will give you an example of how to setup Aurelia to use Jquery/Bootstrap, but you need to use aurelia-cli to setup your project. Tutorial walks you thru it.

Then you need to add info to project/aurelia_project/aurelia.json (created by aurelia-cli) so framework knows how to use Bootstrap/Jquery. This is also in the tutorial.

I've been able to simply (as done in the tutorial):

```
    <require from="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"></require>
```

In src/app.html and copy/paste a drop down menu from Bootstrap components website and it worked!

However, some stuff didn't, like Button with Popup (Popup didn't popup), or Large Modal. Modal did work, just didn't display the title.

May be something I'm missing though, but was stoked to get the dropdown menu working!